# Efficient query to count and calculate average in Cassandra

Tags: php, cassandra

I have a table `datavalue` with data of almost one year for each `client` in a interval `eventtime` of 15 min. I want to create another table `datavalue_by_hour` where i will store data from `datavalue` in a 1 hour interval. For that i need to:

1. Get distinct values for `client` and `eventhour`;
2. Calculate the `avg(activepower)` for the `client` and `eventhour` for each row of the above result;
3. Count the number of `activepower` values used in the average function above.

The problem is, in mysql or postgres this can be easily made with almost one instruction. With Cassandra i guess the only way is by looping through each results and apply another query until the final result is achieved..? This seems a lot inefficient, is there any other way of achieving a structure like this in a more efficient way?

```
AFH0AEE00A0BHC  2016-05-24 18:00:00+0000    0.067   4
AFH0AEE00AGCEC  2016-05-24 19:00:00+0000    0.081   4
AFH0ADE0ACDAAE  2016-05-24 20:00:00+0000    0.068   3
AFH0AEE00AGFEC  2016-05-24 21:00:00+0000    0.032   4
```

My initial datavalue table has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE datavalue (
client text,
eventhour bigint,
eventtime timestamp,
activepower double,
activepowerclassification double,
dstoffset double,
PRIMARY KEY (( pt, eventhour ), eventtime));
```

And a example of the dataset in the `datavalue` table (+10000000 rows):

```
AFH0AEE00BFEFB  1473847200  2016-09-14 10:00:00+0000    0.042   0.0 1.0
AFH0AEE00BFEFB  1473847200  2016-09-14 10:15:00+0000    0.056   0.0 1.0
AFH0AEE00BFEFB  1473847200  2016-09-14 10:30:00+0000    0.075   0.0 1.0
AFH0AEE00BFEFB  1473847200  2016-09-14 10:45:00+0000    0.102   0.0 1.0
A0C0AEAFIFEAHE  1472882400  2016-09-03 06:00:00+0000    0.0 0.0 1.0
A0C0AEAFIFEAHE  1472882400  2016-09-03 06:15:00+0000    0.0 0.0 1.0
A0C0AEAFIFEAHE  1472882400  2016-09-03 06:30:00+0000    0.0 0.0 1.0
A0C0AEAFIFEAHE  1472882400  2016-09-03 06:45:00+0000    0.0 0.0 1.0
AFH0ACFB00CD0F  1452693600  2016-01-13 14:00:00+0000    0.244   0.0 0.0
AFH0ACFB00CD0F  1452693600  2016-01-13 14:15:00+0000    0.244   0.0 0.0
AFH0ACFB00CD0F  1452693600  2016-01-13 14:30:00+0000    0.242   0.0 0.0
AFH0ACFB00CD0F  1452693600  2016-01-13 14:45:00+0000    0.244   0.0 0.0
A0C0AEAFIEE0DC  1466319600  2016-06-19 07:00:00+0000    0.036   0.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your Schema Add dstCount, dstSum and dstAvg :

```
CREATE TABLE datavalue (
    client text,
    eventhour bigint,
    eventtime timestamp,
    activepower double,
    activepowerclassification double,
    dstoffset double,
    powerCount bigint static,
    powerSum double static,
    powerAvg double static,
PRIMARY KEY (( client, eventhour ), eventtime));
```

I have used static column, here is the doc

> A static column is a special column that is shared by all the rows of the same partition. Let’s take an example: suppose that we want to store per-user bills that needs to be paid and keep a per-user balance amount of what remains to be paid. The invariant we want to maintain is that the balance is always the sum of all unpaid bills:

Before inserting new record use this query to select current powerCount and powerSum for the specific client and eventhour

Let you are inserting record

```
client          eventhour   eventtime                  activepower                  
AFH0AEE00BFEFB  1473847200  2016-09-14 10:00:00+0000   0.040
```

The query will be

```
 SELECT powerCount,powerSum 
   FROM datavalue 
 WHERE client = 'AFH0AEE00BFEFB' AND eventhour = 1473847200 LIMIT 1;
```

Now you get the current powerCount and powerSum
Let `powerCount = 4 and powerSum = 0.275`
So updated data

```
powerSum = powerSum + 0.040 = 0.315
powerCount = powerCount + 1  = 5  
powerAvg = powerSum/powerCount =  0.063
```

Now insert the record along with new powerSum, powerCount and powerAvg

Comment: Seems good! I will try to apply this and let you know the results! Many thanks

Comment: Try this and let me know